# How can I find out why Ubuntu with SSD takes so long to boot?

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 on an SSD and it takes more than 3 minutes to boot

My system:

```
4.8.0-30-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 03:43:27 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

laptop Asus k501lb

```
allex@allex-K501LB:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 4.100s (firmware) + 5.372s (loader) + 8.373s (kernel) + 3min 734ms (userspace) = 3min 18.581s
```

SSD with Ubuntu:
[image]

Drive with Windows 10:
[image]

---

[Bootchart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzgq0Dy3V4eoNmdXeklyTDVsNHc/view)

---

[`dmesg` output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23645270/)

Comment: [bootchart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzgq0Dy3V4eoNmdXeklyTDVsNHc/view)

Comment: [dmesg log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzgq0Dy3V4eoU0lES3B5UzRzMUU/view)

Comment: Colin lan King, [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzgq0Dy3V4eoMzhFeDVCU0F3ajg) with this command

Comment: The dmesg output is clearly showing that the nouveau driver is causing boot delays between 15.84 and 98.98 seconds into the kernel boot, so that's the root cause.  I think filing a bug on LaunchPad against "linux" is the next best step to getting this looked at by the Ubuntu kernel team

Answer (score 2):

Systemd can inform you of services that may have taking a while to execute during boot, use:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Comment: Colin lan King, blame in log file in the my commits

Comment: OK, that doesn't look too bad to me. I wonder what is the root problem